# Jest/Node.js - Problems mocking a instance method of a class

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a script which i create a record in document table in dynamoDB.
This creation method is called from my documentModel, as below:

```
class Document {


constructor(props) {
    this['createdAt'] = Date.now()
    this['updatedAt'] = Date.now()
    this['isDeleted'] = false
    this['isUploaded'] = false
    this['isDownloaded'] = false

Object.keys(props).forEach((key) => {
  this[key] = props[key]
})

this['signalTrackerId'] = getRequestContext().signalTrackerId
  }

  async create() {
    const params = {
      TableName,
      Item: { ...this },
      ConditionExpression: `attribute_not_exists(fileName)`,
    }
    return dynamodb.insertItem(params).catch((err) => {
      if (err.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException') {
        throw new TraytError('debug')
          .setCode(1002)
          .setDetails({ message: 'FileName already exists' })
      }
      throw new TraytError('error', err)
        .setCode(1002)
        .setDetails({ message: 'Unknown DynamoDB error' })
    })
  }
```

and called from my script here:

```
const Document = require('@model/documentModel')
const createDocumentAndReferral = async (input) => {
const document = new Document({
 recordId,
 fileName: `regression-test___${recordId}.jpg`,
})
await document.create()
```

I mocked my Document methods like this:

```
jest.mock('@model/documentModel', () => {
  return {
    Document: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      create: jest.fn().jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockedDocument)),
    })),
  };
});
```

as i want that create method returns mockedDocument, but when i run the test, i receive the following error:

```
Error: Document is not a constructor, Stack: TypeError: Document is not a constructor
```

Does somebody know how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to wire things up a bit more like the following:

```
const document = new Document({
 recordId,
 fileName: `regression-test___${recordId}.jpg`,
})

mockCreate = jest.spyOn(document, 'create').mockImplementation(() => {
  return Promise.resolve(mockedDocument);
});
```

or:

```
const document = new Document({
 recordId,
 fileName: `regression-test___${recordId}.jpg`,
});

document.create = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(mockedDocument);
```

Comment: and should i remove the jest.mock('@model/documentModel') stuff?

Comment: That is correct @RafaelPolonio. The purpose of `jest.fn()` is to create individual mock functions to mock callbacks or as a placeholder for functions you want to spy on or control the behavior of during the test.